# Non-linear root finding algorithm "not making any progress"

Tags: algorithms, systems-of-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to use an algorithmic root finder (namely, the CERN ROOT https://root.cern.ch implementation of the GNU Scientific Library's MultiRootFinder) to solve for the unknowns, $x$ and $y$, in the following system:

[image]

This system describes the solution to a localization problem (about which I've posted before). That is, given the coordinates, $[x_i,y_i]$, of three parties, the velocity $s$ of some signal, and the time, $t_i$, at which each party "saw" the signal, I want to determine the coordinates, $[x,y]$, of the source. This is a 2D solution as, in this case, we can assume the three parties and the observer to be coplanar.

Since I want to solve for only two unknowns (and since the root finder complains if I provide all three), I've fed the algorithm the first two equations. I then chose the initial point to be the center of the circle circumscribed by the three parties (although, notably, I know the source to be outside of this circle). I then set the iterations to the maximum possible value.

What I get is the error "root finder not making any progress". I'm quite certain this is an issue of the mathematics, as opposed to some issue with the code. So, what mistake have I made here?

Apologies if this is a basic question. I'm quite unfamiliar with this topic.

Comment: So is $s$ just a number? In other words do you actually know the speed, not the velocity (which is a vector)? And how does the signal "turn"? It seems to me that if all three observers ever observe a signal that is moving at a constant velocity then they have to be collinear.

Comment: Is it possible that you have already converged on a solution, and that insignificant rounding errors prevent the algorithm from recognising this? Have you looked at how closely your equations are satisfied by the algorithm's final approximation? (It might help to _decrease_ the iteration count in this case.)

Comment: Or is it instead that the signal radiates outward in all directions from a source point at a fixed speed and these are the times when it hit those points?

Comment: @Ian Yes. Sorry, I should've written speed. I know the speed of the signal, the coordinates of the observers, and the time of arrival. And, yes, the signal radiates from a fixed point at a fixed speed, and time $t_i$ is the time of arrival at party $i$.

Comment: If you plug the first equation into the second and compare the result with the third, you can see that the system is inconsistent unless $s(t_3 - t_1) = 0$. That may be the cause.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for the suggestion. In this case, I know the source to be outside the circle circumscribed by the three observers and, therefore, the initial point I'm using cannot be the solution. I'll try decreasing the iteration count (although, it doesn't immediately make sense to me how this would help... could you elaborate, maybe?) thanks

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, my mistake! I've written it incorrectly here. The third equation should have $s(t_1 - t_3)$ (I have checked that it is written correctly in the code).

Comment: Good. Then note that the third equation [or any of the three] is redundant. Does it help if you remove it from the input?

Comment: Keith, have you looked at the final approximation, as I suggested? Is it close to the solution?

Comment: @DanielFischer That's what I'm doing now, actually. I've fed the algorithm only the first two equations since, as you pointed out, any of the three can be tossed out.

Comment: @DanielFischer: (i) It is not entirely redundant; the first two equations will in general have two solutions, by symmetry, so you need the third to disambiguate. But unless all the arithmetic is exact (which it isn't, by the way), it will make the equations formally insoluble. (ii) The OP already said that they had removed the third equation.

Comment: @TonyK I'm checking to see what I can do with that. With this particular framework, it doesn't actually produce the solution if this error occurs. I'll try to get around that.

Comment: Keith, try it first with (say) three iterations. Then four, etc, until it starts to complain.

Comment: @TonyK Hmmm. I started with three iterations, and produced a new error "exceeded max iterations, reached tolerance is not sufficient", where my tolerance is set to 1E-06 (just the default value). When I reach 10 iterations, I get the "not making progress" error.

Comment: Well, play with the tolerance! Or you could strike out in a completely new direction, by looking into computing the intersection points of two hyperbolas. See [LORAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LORAN) $-$ if it was doable in the 1940's, it's doable now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could just be that the initial guesses are not sufficiently good.

What I suppose is that the initial equations are
$$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}=s(t_1-t)\tag 1$$
$$\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}=s(t_2-t)\tag 2$$
$$\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}=s(t_3-t)\tag 3$$
where the $t_i$'s are the real times and $t$ the time at which the signal was observed.

In a *preliminary* step, rewrite these squaring
$$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=s^2(t_1-t)^2\tag 4$$
$$(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2=s^2(t_2-t)^2\tag 5$$
$$(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2=s^2(t_3-t)^2\tag 6$$
Subtract $(4)$ from $(5)$ and $(6)$, expand and simplify to get
$$2(x_1-x_2)x+2(y_1-y_2)y+2s^2(t_2-t_1)t=(x_1^2+y_1^2-s^2 t_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2-s^2 t_2^2)\tag 7$$
$$2(x_1-x_3)x+2(y_1-y_3)y+2s^2(t_3-t_1)t=(x_1^2+y_1^2-s^2 t_1^2)-(x_3^2+y_3^2-s^2 t_3^2)\tag 8$$ Solve $(7)$ and $(8)$ for $x$ and $y$ (these are two linear equations). The resulting solutions $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$. Plug these results in $(4)$, $(5)$ or $(6)$ to get a quadratic in $t$; for sure select the root which is smaller that the minimum of $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$.

Now, you should be ready for solving $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ for $x$, $y$, and $t$.

However, instead of using an equation solver, I would prefer to use a minimizer.

For illustration purposes, consider the following data (with $s=343$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
i & x_i & y_i & t_i \\
 1 & 100 & 150 & 1.3685 \\
 2 & 200 & 150 & 1.0777 \\
 3 & 300 & 100 & 0.7876
\end{array}
\right)$$

The above procedure leads to $t=0.1911$, $x=503.08$, $y=124.96$. The optimization leads to almost identical results.

The data were generated using $x=500$, $y=125$, $t=0.2$ and the times were rounded to four decimal places.